# Using MRTK 2.4.0, Unity, Tutorials Do Not Work, Can't Figure Out How to Configure it to Work

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

Brand new HoloLens 2 using latest versions of all the tools. I can't get the most basic tutorial to produce the expected output. I have done the whole thing multiple times to ensure I am following the directions exactly. It builds in Unity and loads to my HL2 device. I have gone all the way to lesson 6 and things don't work as the documentation says. Can anyone point me to something that actually works for a point of beginning. Right now MRTK is just a trial and error operation. Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you get? It's hard to tell by your question what is going wrong.

Comment: Could you indicate what “lesson 6” is? Is it from Microsoft Documentation? We recommend you to start learning HoloLens development from here: [Mixed Reality Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/development)

Comment: @frankhermes I posted a lengthy discussion [here on github 2405] (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/mixed-reality/issues/2405), What is going wrong? I don't know? The docs on Microsoft tutorial don't tell, explain, or show what it is supposed to do. The recommended start - that is what I'm using, and it does not match the actual results if you follow the tutorials. You cannot learn if the samples are not up to date with the tools.

Comment: @hernando see the comment to frankhermes

Comment: Could you double-check the link you post? It returns 404 code and is not visible to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty annoying problem in the MRTK which is about 'solvers' and project built in Release ARM64.

[MixedRealityToolkit-Unity Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/7624)

It's probably a very specific case for a lot of people but I was naturally building like that all of my projects and MRTK demos and nothing was working as expected.
I spent a lot of time to identify what I was doing wrong.
Maybe you are in this case ...

As others guys asked, we need more infos about what is not working, your differents tries etc .. to help you.